# Silverlight 4.0 Form Initialization Problem

Tags: xaml, silverlight, f#, silverlight-4.0

I am getting a very strange error on one of my Silverlight 4.0 pages. I have a form that has a "save" button which is disabled by default. This form gets populated by a bunch of user-specified defaults, which come from an asynchronous server call (`MyFacade.getFormDefaults` below). When the user changes one of the fields (after it's populated), I want the "save" button to become enabled.

I think I have the logic correct, but I'm getting a very strange error that I can't find much useful information on. The error is: `System.InvalidOperationException: The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.`

Below is a very simplified version of what I have...

**profile.fs:**

```
type profile() as this =
    inherit UriUserControl("/whatever;component/profile.xaml", "profile")

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable isFormLoaded : bool
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable btnSave : Button
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable txtEmail : TextBox

    // constructor
    do
        this.isFormLoaded <- false

        // make the "this" values point at the XAML fields
        this.btnSave <- this?btnSave
        this.txtEmail <- this?txtEmail

        // get the form defaults and send them to
        MyFacade.getFormDefaults(new Action<_>(this.populateFormDefaults))
        ()

    member this.populateFormDefaults (formDefaults : MyFormDefaultsUIVO array option) =
        // populate this.txtEmail with the default value here
        this.isFormLoaded <- true // set the form to be loaded once that's done
        ()

    // enable the "Save" button when the user modifies a form field
    member this.userModifiedForm (sender : obj) (args : EventArgs) =
        // **** EXCEPTION OCCURS ON THE LINE BELOW ****
        if this.isFormLoaded then
            this.btnSave.IsEnabled <- true
        ()
```

**profile.xaml:**

```
<nav:Page Name="profile" Loaded="formLoaded">
    <TextBox Name="txtEmail" TextChanged="userModifiedForm "/>
    <Button Name="btnSave" IsEnabled="False"/>
</nav:Page>
```

Even if I get rid of all the `isFormLoaded` logic, and simply set `this.btnSave.IsEnabled <- true` inside of `this.userModifiedForm`, I get the same error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception - "The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized" - is generated by the F# runtime when an object is accessed before being fully initialized.

Accessing `this` - whether to check `isFormLoaded` or `btnSave.IsEnabled` - before the constructor has run will cause the error. Have you verified that `userModifiedForm` is only called after the constructor?

Comment: I suppose one of the XAML fields (like a TextBox, ComboBox, or CheckBox) is triggering a TextChanged or SelectionChanged event and calling `userModifiedForm`. So, yes, you're correct... but how do I prevent this from happening? It's annoying that Silverlight will trigger those events before the form is fully constructed.

Comment: If this is the problem, the easiest solution will probably be to only attach `userModifiedForm` to `txtEmail` at the end of the constructor instead of in the xaml file.

Comment: wmeyer's suggestion should work - and in Silverlight's defense: since it's not integrated with the F# type system, I'm not sure how it could automatically avoid causing this problem.